# Show that $\frac1{x^p}=\frac1{\Gamma(p)}\int_0^\infty u^{p-1}e^{-xu}\,du$

Tags: gamma-function

$$\frac1{x^p}=\frac1{\Gamma(p)}\int_0^\infty u^{p-1}e^{-xu}\,du$$
Hello I am having problems to proof this statment, I really don´t see where to start.

Comment: You know gamma function, right? Use substitution to change the integral so it becomes like gamma function. In this case, try to let $xu = t$.

Comment: Thanks, now I get it.